# Backdrop-filter not affecting borders in iOS browsers

Tags: ios, border, blur

One of my buttons have a border that wont show as blurred on iOS devices with both safari and chrome. Backdrop-filter only seems to affect the background of the button but not the border on iOS browsers.
FF, chrome and edge on PC show them properly with this code.
I looked thru similar problems on this site but could not find someone with the same problem.

There is alot of css but you can find backdrop filter under `.secondarybutton a`
Here is my code:

```
/*    secondarybutton    */

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) and (min-resolution: 0.001dpcm) {
.secondarybutton:not(*:root) {
padding-bottom: 22px;
}}
@supports (-webkit-touch-callout: none) { 
.secondarybutton {
  -webkit-padding-after: 27px !important;}
}

.secondarybutton .menu-link{
letter-spacing: 1px !important;
}
.secondarybutton .menu-link:hover {
letter-spacing: 3px !important;
}
.secondarybutton{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: none;
  padding: 25px 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 42px 12px rgba( 198, 100, 26, 0.37 );
  text-align: center;

}
.secondarybutton a {
  color: #eb9224 !important;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .05);
  box-shadow: 0 15px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.05 ) !important;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.05 ) !important;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.05 ) !important;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.05 ) !important;
  border-radius: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
  font-weight: 800;
  letter-spacing: 1px !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;  
  backdrop-filter: blur(2.5px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(2.5px);
}
.secondarybutton:hover a {
  letter-spacing: 3px !important;
  color: #1d2647 !important;
}
.secondarybutton a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: 
  linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15), transparent);
  transform: skewX(40deg) translateX(0);
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
}
.secondarybutton:hover a::before {
  transform: skewX(40deg) translateX(200%);
}
.secondarybutton::before,
.secondarybutton::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 40px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #f00;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0.0s;
}
.secondarybutton::before {  
  bottom: -5px;
}
.secondarybutton::after {
  top: -5px;    
}
.secondarybutton:hover::before,
.secondarybutton:hover::after {  
  height: 100%;
  width: 95%;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition-delay: .1s;    
}
.secondarybutton:hover::before {
  bottom: 0;
}
.secondarybutton:hover::after {
  top: 0;   
}
.secondarybutton:before,
.secondarybutton:after{
  background: radial-gradient( #fff07f, #ffe770, #ffd851, #ffcd3c, #ffb42b, #eb9224, #d58022, #a65314   );
  box-shadow: 
  0 0 5px #fbb12c,
  0 0 15px #c0732a,
  0 0 30px #a45620,
  0 0 80px #7c3816;
}
.secondarybutton:hover {
  background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.05 );
}
```

Tried some solutions for similar problems already like moving the backdrop-filters to `.secondarybutton a::before`.
Tried adding `will-change: transform;` to both `.secondarybutton` and `.secondarybutton a`.
Tried adding

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

to `.secondarybutton a`
Tried removing `overflow:hidden;` from `.secondarybutton a`.